# UIViewController - can't become first responder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

anyone knows why UIViewController wouldn't become first responder when I run this code:

```
[self becomeFirstResponder];
NSLog(@"is first resp: %i",[self isFirstResponder]);
```

In the console, I always see the line: "is first resp: 0"

I HAVE canBecomeFirstResponder method:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
return YES;
}
```

I don't even know where to look next....

Comment: I've never used becomeFirstResponder on a UIViewController and I can't figure out why you would need to. It doesn't respond to user input, it's child views do however.

Comment: A responder object only becomes the first responder if the current responder can resign first-responder status (canResignFirstResponder) and the new responder can become first responder.

Who is current First responder?

Comment: Can I ask why is it essential that the UIViewCOntroller be the first responder?

Comment: Nick - I want to detect shakes (with motionEnded method which is sent to first responder only)
Oxigen - I didn't check that, I'll do it.
Corey - As I told to Nick, I need to receive motionEnded message somewhere, and since I chose UIViewController, I need it to be first responder for that

Comment: The undo functionality seems to require the VC to become first responder too.  At least that's how I read it, and got it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update

As I suspected, I assumed wrong about `UIViewController`/`firstResponder` usage.  This [thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/49571#49571) in the apple dev forums talks specifically about getting shaking to work.

### Original Answer

Call `becomeFirstResponder` on the UI element that you want to respond. The events will automatically get forwarded to the `UIViewController` as long as no other objects in the chain implement the touches methods (or at least keep forwarding them up the chain).

Side note: To build on the comments of others, it really doesn't make sense for a `UIViewController` to be the "first" responder. The first responder should be an object with an on screen representation (a `UIView` or one of its subclasses).

Although this may be a completely incorrect statement, there may be undocumented behavior in  `UIViewController` that prevents it from becoming the firstResponder because of these issues (Someone smarter than me may be able to verify the validity of this).

Comment: I agree with you, but how else would you add shake-detection functionality? I can have the method in one of the UIView subclasses, but how can I guarantee that I will always detect shakes unless the method is in the most parent class?

Comment: Good point, i updated my answer with some information I found in the dev forums

Comment: Corey, it worked. The key was to make VC first responder in ViewDidAppear.

Comment: Now I can only detect shakes on startup. I have UIScrollView with bunch of nested UIViews, and it is still a challenge to make them detect shakes as well.... :(

Comment: You may have to override the motion began/ended methods in the subviews or at least the scrollview as well and handle the forwarding manually. Passing events passing through UIScrollView has been tricky, it generally likes to swallow (touch) events. Not sure about motion events.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you set your UIViewController to be first responder *after* you have assigned some view to your window instance.

Comment: NUGGET OF USEFUL INFORMATION ABOVE! Calling [self resignFirstResponder] on my view controller was failing because I had already removed its view from the screen

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a UIScrollView in that UIViewController?

Comment: I believe that UIScrollView is taking your firstResponder status away since it wants to get the tap before it is passed on.  For all intents and purposes though, I think you're fine since the shake detection mechanism will go through the UIScrollView to your view controller if it needs to.

Comment: that's the point - I can't detect shakes anywhere in the code. I started to dig in it and found that VC doesn't become first responder