# IOS: iPad keyboard always visible?

Tags: objective-c, ios, keyboard, uitextfield, first-responder

In my application, I want the keyboard to always be visible in a view. I can do it with a textfield in this way:

```
[textField1 becomeFirstResponder]; //in viewWillAppear
```

but I don't have a text field explicitly in the view itself?

Comment: If there are no text field or text view, then what the keypad will do?

Comment: then, you're right; there are some textfield but I won't that my keyboard appear for becomeFirstResponder of a textfield and I ask if there are other method to show the keyboard. Instead is there something to disable the button that leave the keyboard? I mean the lower right button.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469876/uiviewcontroller-cant-become-first-responder