# When would a view controller become the first responder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, first-responder

I'm learning about the responder chain in iOS and about first responders and I was wondering , what are the use cases that a UIViewController would become or need to become a first responder?

For example, I'm doing an animation on a UILabel so that for every pixel the user drags their finger, the label moves with it. I'm overriding `touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and all those methods as you should but I need to be able to tell where the user is dragging, outside the context of the view. I feel like that's a potential use case where I would want my view controller to be the first responder and have all the methods in with the view controller code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The View Controller should normally be first responder until a UIControl takes over.
Please see this question for a better response.
[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469876/uiviewcontroller-cant-become-first-responder)

I think however, you will be better served by using a UIGestureRecognizer [See Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)